# dhclient triggered by udev event give only IPV6 IP

Tags: udev, dhclient

I have an udev event that when a net adapter is plugged, dhclient is run to attribute an IP, I want to attribute an IPv4 but it always give me IPv6 address (which I don't want, When I run dhclient from the command line it always give me IPv4 address), here's my rule :

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net",KERNELS!="eth0",KERNELS=="eth*",RUN+="/usr/sbin/dhclient -4 %k"
```

and here is the result :

```
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 2a02:a03f:6080:7200:9c9:73cd:af73:652  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a02:a03f:6080:7200:215:5dff:fe01:25d5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe01:25d5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:01:25:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 167  bytes 43826 (43.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 888 (888.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I'm running on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04